# Specifying section name for code in GCC

Tags: gcc

I know that GCC lets you use `__attribute__((section(".mysection")))` for a function definition to specify what section to put the code in. I have a bunch of code that needs to go in a specific section and it's fairly tedious to have to decorate every function with this. Is there a way to compile a file while globally specifying on the command line which section the code gets put inside?

Comment: It's not the answer to your question but could simplify your life a bit. You can have something like this : #define MYSECTION __attribute__((section(".mysection"))). And then you just add MYSECTION with the prototype instead of the whole attribute text.

Comment: @TimF: I'm already doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it fits you can chage the linker script to put specific object files into specific sections.

The following example is extrapolated from [this resource](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html)

> The following example is a complete linker script. It tells the linker to read all of the sections from file `all.o` and place them at the start of output section `outputa` which starts at location `0x10000`. All of section `.input1` from file `foo.o` follows immediately, in the same output section. All of section `.input2` from foo.o goes into output section `outputb`, followed by section `.input1` from `foo1.o`. All of the remaining .input1 and `.input2` sections from any files are written to output section `outputc`.

```
SECTIONS 
{
    outputa 0x10000 :
    {
       all.o
       foo.o (.input1)
    }

    outputb :
    {
       foo.o (.input2)
       foo1.o (.input1)
    }

    outputc :
    {
       *(.input1)
       *(.input2)
    }
}
```

So what you can do is to design your project to isolate all function of a specific section into an object file that will be put into the desired section.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know that the linker script allows you to specify the object file it extracts the section from.