# Execute a library function from RAM memory using Keil

Tags: c, linker, arm, keil

I have a **lludivv7m.o** which is included inside the Standard Arm C Library. And I need to place the **__aeabi_uldivmod** function only in RAM.

In the linker script. I can do the following:

```
lludivv7m.o(+RO)
```

But this will move the whole file into RAM.
is it possible to move this specific function? And others if needed?

Comment: Maybe something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120764/specifying-section-name-for-code-in-gcc.